# ASAP shower needs to be fixed i have kids someone

Tags: shower

changed out my diverter stem in my 3 handle shower because it wasn't working right but when I put the new stem in and tested it I wouldn't work still so I tried removing the stem and now it comes apart and only the nuts to turn it will come out but the stem it self will not how can I get the rest of the stem out with out having to replace everything behind my tile wall that I do not have access too

Comment: Pictures might make this a lot easier. Could you also give more details on what you mean by 'won't work'?

Comment: Take a deep breath, relax, it's gonna be OK. The kids will appreciate a day or two without a shower!  Get a few clear, focused, detailed pics of the issue, then 1 or 2 overview pics to show context. [Edit] your post to add the pics in (click the "sun & mountain" button above the text entry box). Tell us exactly _what_ isn't working right - No water flow, minimal water flow, leaking everywhere? Lots of possibilities for "not working".